# Pythonpipbuilder: resolve dependencies - list index out of range

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

**Description:**
I am trying to use sam build with the following requirements but its throwing the error: Pythonpipbuilder: resolve dependencies - list index out of range

- pyotp
- ulid-py
- aws_encryption_sdk
- boto3
- requests
- attrs
- cryptography

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Create a virtual env.
2. Activate virtual env in a terminal
3. pip install -r requirements.txt
4. sam build

**Observed result:**
Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - list index out of range

**Expected result:**
Build Succeeded

**Additional environment details**
Amazon Linux 2 Workspace
Python3.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you encounter this problem you have to use sam build --use-container in other to go around the problem with the requirements.txt
Its a well known issue and a GitHub issue has been submitted https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-builders/issues/229#issuecomment-841407255

Answer (score 0):

I had the same failure when my serverless application specified Runtime as python3.6, while the environment was using Python3.7.

Comment: thank you for your answers, it seems to be a well known issue with some dependencies and it requires the user to use sam build --use-container